# Spring MVC JPA exception org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException

Tags: java, mysql, spring, jpa

I'm new to Spring JPA stuff. I'm learning now. I got weird error while trying to insert data in mysql database.

I made sure that I have a the table and database setup correctly as same as my

```
mysql> show columns in empolyee in test;


| Field | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |

| id    | int(6)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment | 
  eid   | int(6)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| name  | varchar(40) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| role  | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
```

My entity class:-

```
      @Entity
     public class Employee extends AbstractPersistable<Long> {

    private int eid;
    private String name;
    private String role;

    public Employee(){

    }

    public Employee(int aeid, String aname, String arole){
        eid=aeid;
        name = aname;
        role = arole;
       }
     }
```

Error:-

```
 HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is  org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: Table 'test.employee' doesn't exist; 
nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: 
Table 'test.employee' doesn't exist
```

Comment: Maybe you are connected to an other database?

Comment: empolyee and Employee are not same? is it typo?

Comment: @Atilla Ozgur, you actually gave a right answer as a comment. I'd suggest you to post it as an answer. This is a typo: `empolyee` in DB and `employee` in java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your table name in database is empolyee

```
@Entity
public class Employee extends AbstractPersistable<Long>
```

Here you are not specifying @Table annotation hence JPA will take table name as class name which is Employee which doesn't exist in your database. Hence change this

```
@Entity
@Table(name="empolyee")  //this exists in database
public class Employee extends AbstractPersistable<Long>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It's working now. Jut a question why auto generated filed id always start from 6? I tried few others, always start from 6

Answer (score 0):

Case sensitivity of MySQL table names depends on operating system:

> In MySQL, databases correspond to directories within the data
>   directory. Each table within a database corresponds to at least one
>   file within the database directory (and possibly more, depending on
>   the storage engine). Consequently, the case sensitivity of the
>   underlying operating system plays a part in the case sensitivity of
>   database and table names. This means database and table names are not
>   case sensitive in Windows, and case sensitive in most varieties of
>   Unix. One notable exception is Mac OS X, which is Unix-based but uses
>   a default file system type (HFS+) that is not case sensitive. However,
>   Mac OS X also supports UFS volumes, which are case sensitive just as
>   on any Unix.

So, you need to set table name in the correct case :

```
 @Entity @Table(name = "empolyee")
 public class Employee extends AbstractPersistable<Long>  { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your entity class annotation to below.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="empolyee")
```